# List the installed marketplace products

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-marketplace

I have a project in GCP and there are other users as well using my project.

I just wanted to know the list of marketplace products that are currently installed.

*I tried searching for documents related to it, but I could find most of documents about deploying a product or managing our own product in marketplace.*

Is there a way to find this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use marketplace on GCP, at the same time Deployment manager is used.

So in order for you to get a sense of all products created through Marketplace, please do the following

```
1. Menu 
2. Deployment Manager
3. Deployments
```

Now if you want to know who deployed what, do this

```
1. Menu
2. Home
3. Activity
4. Filter choose deployment for resource type
5. Go
```

Here is another [way](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/reference/latest/deployments/list?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22danytest1%22%7D), and you just need to put your project ID and execute.

Through gcloud command:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments list
```

Comment: Add this command to your answer: **gcloud deployment-manager deployments list**.