# Listing Google Cloud Marketplace Purchases using Asset Inventory API and/or Billing API in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-asset-inventory, google-cloud-marketplace

I am currently working on a Java application that utilizes the Google Cloud Asset Inventory API to list all the assets within various projects of a company. Now, I am facing the challenge of listing all the products purchased on the Google Cloud Marketplace for each project.

After exploring the documentation, I couldn't find a direct way to list all the Google Cloud Marketplace products associated with a specific project using the Cloud Asset API. Therefore, I believe I may need to use the Google Cloud Billing API to achieve this.

My main question is: How can I distinguish between the "native" Google Cloud services and the products that have been purchased from the Google Cloud Marketplace using the Billing API? I need to generate a list that clearly shows the products from the Marketplace, similar to the one depicted in the screenshot below.

[image: Goocgle Cloud Marketplace orders lis]

Any guidance or code examples on how to differentiate between native Google services and Marketplace purchases using the Billing API would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

As per [dany L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862338/list-the-installed-marketplace-products), for products used from Marketplace, Deployment manager is used as well. You can try to go to

```
Menu > Deployments Manager > Deployments
```

Or you can try to run a command

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments list
```